# Iterar coleção de objeto ActiveX com interop latebound em c# (COMAdminCatalogCollection)

Tags: c#, activex, interoperabilidade

Eu preciso iterar coleções de objetos COM+/ActiveX com interop utilizando latebound no C#. Neste momento a minha necessidade é iterar a coleção de objetos ActiveX `COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection`, retorno do método `GetCollection("Applications")` do componente `COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog`. Mas no momento trata-se de uma POC que será utilizada com outros componentes COM+/ActiveX proprietários, de desenvolvimento interno, e por isso preciso desenvolver essa solução utilizando late bound. Como eu devo fazer o boxing o objeto `object` para ser iterável?

## COMPlus.cs

```
public abstract class COMPlus
{
    public object COMObject { get; private set; }
    public System.Type COMObjectType { get; private set; }

    protected COMPlus(string progId)
    {
        this.COMObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId));
        this.COMObjectType = this.COMObject.GetType();
    }

    protected COMPlus(object comObject, string progId)
    {
        this.COMObject = comObject;
        this.COMObjectType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId);
    }
}
```

## COMAdminCatalog.cs

```
public class COMAdminCatalog : COMPlus
{
    public COMAdminCatalog() : base("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog") { }
    public COMAdminCatalog(object comObject) : base(comObject, "COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog") { }

    public void Connect(string serverAddress)
    {

    }

    public COMAdminCatalogCollection GetCollection(string collectionName)
    {
        return new COMAdminCatalogCollection(
            base.COMObjectType.InvokeMember("GetCollection",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null,
                base.COMObject,
                new object[] { (object)collectionName }));
    }
}
```

## COMAdminCatalogCollection.cs

```
public class COMAdminCatalogCollection : COMPlus
{
    public COMAdminCatalogCollection() : base("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog") { }
    public COMAdminCatalogCollection(object comObject) : base(comObject, "COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog") { }

    public void Populate()
    {
        base.COMObjectType.InvokeMember("Populate",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null,
            base.COMObject, null);
    }
}
```

## Toolbox.cs

```
public static class Toolbox
{
    public static void CreateApp(string appName, string serverAddress = null)
    {
        COMAdminCatalog comAdminCatalog = new Interop.COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog();
        COMAdminCatalogCollection comAdminCatalogCollection;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(serverAddress))
        {
            comAdminCatalog.Connect(serverAddress);
        }

        comAdminCatalogCollection = comAdminCatalog.GetCollection("Applications");

        comAdminCatalogCollection.Populate();

        // aqui deve começar a brincadeira iterando a coleção de aplicações pra verificar se a aplicação solicitada já existe ou não.
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta mas ainda assim esta sugestão pode ser útil: em vez de usar **object** ou mesmo a interface do componente importado, use o tipo ***dynamic*** para declarar a variável que receberá a referência ao ActiveX. Isso facilita muito a vida e segundo alguns é até mais performático para interação *.Net* com *COM+/ActiveX*.

Comment: O dynamic só está disponível a partir do .Net 4, eu preciso de retrocompatibilidade com o 2.0, o que me permite ir no máximo até o 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a resposta no stackoverflow.com. O pulo do gato é utilizar o método `_NewEnum()`, padrão do Interop, pra obter um `System.Collection.IEnumarator`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789124/iterate-activex-collection-object-with-late-bind-interop-on-c-sharp-comadmincat